# How can we use <picture> tag instead of "background-image"?

Tags: html, css, tags, xhtml, background-image

i want to use different images when opened in different devices. i have set a background image in the paragraph tag.

```
<p style="background-image: url('outdoor.jpg"); color: #fff; font-size: 20px"> blablablabla</p>
```

how can i use the below  tag instead of the above "background-image".

```
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 950px)" srcset="outdoor.jpg">
    <source media="(min-width: 765px)" srcset="wall.jpg">
    <img src="plants.jpg" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```

Comment: Hi! This looks like it can be a good question, but please add detail on what the problem is that you're having. When you use the code you showed, what happens? What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't achieve this with inline style. Use a stylesheet with media queries instead.

```
<p id="myParagraph">blablablabla</p>
```

and

```
#myParagraph {
    background-image: url('plants.jpg");
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 765px) {
    #myParagraph {
        background-image: url('wall.jpg");
    }
}

@media (min-width: 950px) {
    #myParagraph {
        background-image: url('outdoor.jpg");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

try linking it with the `<a>` tag or the `<link>` tag like this:-
`<a href=""></a>` or do the same with link